# Why doesn't either of my Cloud SQL databases have an Outgoing IP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

In order to set up two-way replication as per [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/setting-bi-directional-replication-for-cloud-sql-for-postgresql/) but there is no Outgoing IP showing for my two Cloud SQL PostgreSQL databases.

Both are public, and show just the public IP and connection name (typical Cloud SQL connection string).

I haven't authorized any networks to connect to them yet (it seems I need the other's Outgoing IP to do that for its fellow) so prior to replication flow I've just been connecting to them with cloud-sql-proxy from local and direct from my app engine app.

It looks like this is by design as one of them did have until I deleted its fellow and cloned it, I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Did you assign a "Public IP" under "Instance IP assignment" in the "Connections" section for Cloud SQL? Edit your question and include what you configured.

Comment: This is reported in Google's bugtracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/324827392 (with no solution yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Cloud SQL databases only have an outgoing IP when high availability (multi-zone) is turned off as below. Perhaps there's other reasons, this was my issue.

[Example: setting to single zone reactivates the outgoing IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mZwx.png)